# CKEditor Spellcheck Error

Tags: ckeditor

The spellcheck option in ckeditor is throwing this error when use is attempted. Once the error window appears the screen just freezes unless you go into another menu. I am unsure if the recent update has contributed to this issue.

Wordpress 4.9.4
CiviCRM 4.7.29

Error Message:
"WebSpellChecker.net server: The specified customer ID is intended for use with CKEditor only. For more information, please contact us at support@webspellchecker.net or submit a ticket at webspellchecker.net website."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, in both Chrome and Firefox, due to the Referrer-Policy setting of my site. Error was raised with Referrer-Policy: same-origin (or stricter). To resolve it, relax the policy to origin-when-cross-origin for CK Editor.

Apparently, webspellchecker uses the referrer to check if the originating page is CK Editor.